# How can you see you Data Extension subscriber count by day

Tags: dataextensions

One of my DE list has recently been getting fake subscribers. I would like to see how many subscribers this DE is getting a day. Is there a feature in the UI that allows me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the canned reports are List, not Data Extension based.  Best bet would be to write a [Query Activity](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/) to count the rows and write it to a report Data Extension.  From there you can set up a [Data Extract](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/data_extract_activity/) and [File Transfer](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/file_transfer_activity/) and run it on a schedule in [Automation Studio](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/).

1. Query
2. Data Extract
3. File Transfer

The query could be something as simple as this:

```
select
'DataExtension1' as DataExtensionName
, count(*) Counter
from DataExtension1
```

...that writes to a Data Extensions with these columns:

```
DataExtensionName, Text(200), not null
Counter, Number, not null
CreatedDate, Date, nullable, defaulted to today's date
```